# Tor browser: Vidalia exited abnormally. Exit code: 139 (32 bit)

Tags: 32-bit, debug, tor

I downloaded Tor Browser Bundle (tor-browser-gnu-linux-i686-2.3.25-4-dev-en-US) for 32-Bit Linux. Whenever I start to run it on my Ubuntu 12.04 OS it shows me;

```
Vidalia exited abnormally.  Exit code: 139
```

And I tried to do following things by reading another post about same problem.

Run tor successfully in debug mode in by opening a terminal in the tor folder and running:

```
./start-tor-browser --debug
```

It shows in terminal like

```
meraj@Meruz:~/Desktop/Upload/tor-browser_en-US$ ./start-tor-browser --debug

Debug enabled.


Starting Vidalia now

Launching Vidalia from: /home/meraj/Desktop/Upload/tor-browser_en-US
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Vidalia exited with the following return code: 139
meraj@Meruz:~/Desktop/Upload/tor-browser_en-US$
```

I dont know what to do. Please help.

Comment: Run tor successfully in debug mode in by opening a terminal in the tor folder and running  ./start-tor-browser --debug. And this doesnot work.

Comment: When you start the software with the `--debug` switch, do you get some output? If yes, please copy the output into your question.